# Recursive function call in shim Context

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-fakes, shim

Given a recursive method, and using Microsoft Fakes, How could I, on first call, call actual method  and call shim implementation on recursive call?

Simplified example:

```
public int RecursiveMethod(int param)
{ 
    //method logic and calls
    RecursiveMethod(callParam); 
    return result;
}
```

Now if I use `ShimsContext` and implement `AllInstances.RecursiveMethod`, I can not reach actual method which I want to test. If I use `ShimsContext.ExecuteWithoutShims(())`, I exit from shims context and no more could fake wanted parts.

I assume there is a flow in my logic, being new to Microsoft Fakes.

Comment: You might be making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Use the input parameter and Stub/Shim any external method calls from the recursive method to drive the test.  You just want to manage the data values, not override the code.  Without seeing the actual RecursiveMethod, hard to offer any alternatives.

Comment: ohh I see, It seems to be a very good idea.